# Unable to insert null values in nullable column via stored procedure in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a SQL table where column is set to `null`. Now I am passing the null value from code via stored procedure and it throws an error which is, `Procedure or function 'MyStoredProcedure' expects parameter '@Parameter', which was not supplied.`

Now Confusing part for me is, if I add null condition and than pass `DBNull.Value`, it works fine but if I pass direct parameter which could be `null` than it throws error. I am trying to understand why? Am I missing something here?

Note: Just for information, passing parameter could be null based on the requirement.

Code:

```
string connString = _dbContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    connection.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("MyStoredProcedure", connection);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    scheduledEndDateTime = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(bulkUpdateSchedule.EndDate) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(bulkUpdateSchedule.EndTime) 
    ? (DateTime?) 
    Convert.ToDateTime(bulkUpdateSchedule.EndDate + " " + bulkUpdateSchedule.EndTime)
    : null;

    //This Fails
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scheduledEndDateTime", scheduledEndDateTime);

    //This Works
    if (scheduledEndDateTime != null)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scheduledEndDateTime", scheduledEndDateTime);
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scheduledEndDateTime", DBNull.Value);
    }

    cmd.ExecuteReader();

    connection.Close();
}
```

Stored Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertScheduledBulkUpdateRecords]
    @scheduledEndDateTime DATETIME,
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
        INSERT INTO ScheduledBulkUpdate (ScheduledEndDateTime)
        VALUES (@scheduledEndDateTime)
END
```

Table Structure screen shot:

[image]

Comment: ``DBNull`` and c# ``null`` are different things

Comment: you can assign default value is SP though: ``@scheduledEndDateTime DATETIME = null``

Comment: @EhsanSajjad So I can only go through this `if...else` route.

Comment: This is because `AddWithValue()` sucks some of the time.

Comment: instead of `if...else` you can potentially use `(object)scheduledEndDateTime ?? DBNull.Value` to coalese the null value. See [?? on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx). Note: you need the object cast to make the two sides comparable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've pretty much answered your own question `null` and [`DBNull.Value`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value(v=vs.110).aspx) are different things. Where `DBNull.Value` means something to the database provider than `null` doesn't.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/934efkk6.aspx) on DBNull:

> Do not confuse the notion of null in an object-oriented programming
>   language with a DBNull object. In an object-oriented programming
>   language, null means the absence of a reference to an object. DBNull
>   represents an uninitialized variant or nonexistent database column.